# Method to use html table rows as check boxes?

Tags: jquery, html, prototypejs

Im working on a rails app and am trying to have each row of an HTML table correspond to a checkbox, and clicking the row select/deselects the checkbox. This is illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/3XZvV/2/

However, I want to keep with Prototype in my rails project so does anyone know how to convert this from jquery to prototype or know of any tutorials to do so?

Heres my (failed) attempt to do so: http://jsfiddle.net/3XZvV/12/

Comment: @Matt http://jsfiddle.net/3XZvV/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Prototype, but you can do it without a library:

```
(function(){   
    var tables = GEBCN('clickable');

    for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
        var trs = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++){
            trs[j].onclick = function(){
               var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input');
               for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
                   if(c[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                       // Set the checked property
                       c[i].checked = !c[i].checked;

                       // Set the checked attribute
                       if(c[i].getAttribute('checked'))
                           c[i].removeAttribute('checked');
                        else
                           c[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                   }
               // Toggle the table rows class
               toggleClass(this, 'selected');
            };
        }
    }

    function GEBCN(c){

        if(document.getElementsByClassName)
            return document.getElementsByClassName(c);

        var els = [];
        var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for(var i = all.length; i;)
            if(hasClass(all[--i], c))
                els.push(all[i]);

        return els;

    };

    function hasClass(el,c){
        var elc = ' '+el.className+' ';
        if(elc.indexOf(' '+c+' ') < 0)
            return false;
        return true;    
    }

    function addClass(el, c){
        if(c.indexOf(' ') >= 0)
            return false;
        if(hasClass(el, c))
            return true;
        el.className += ' '+c;
        return true;
    }

    function removeClass(el, c){
        if(c.indexOf(' ') > -1)
            return false;
        if(!hasClass(el, c))
            return true;
        var elc = (' '+el.className).replace(' '+c, '');
        if(elc.indexOf(' ') == 0)
            elc = elc.substring(1);
            el.className = elc;
        return true;
    }

    function toggleClass(el, c){
        if(hasClass(el, c))
            removeClass(el,c);
        else
            addClass(el,c);
    }
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/742bv/)

Comment: Hey Paul I ended up using your script! Though long, pure javascript is just cleaner and most guaranteed to work as told. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do ya:

```
$$('table.clickable tr').each(function(e) {
   e.observe('click', function() {
    e.toggleClassName('selected')
    });     
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XZvV/14/

**Update:**

```
$$('table.clickable tr').each(function(e) {
   e.observe('click', function() {
    e.toggleClassName('selected')
    var ch = $(e).down('input')
        if(ch.checked) {
            ch.checked = false;
        }
       else {
           ch.checked = true;
       }    
    });     
})
```

Comment: @Diodeus Perfect! Youre a lifesaver.

Comment: It's a wonder Prototype is still in my head after these years of jQuery.

Comment: You should also update the checked property and attribute of the input to make it behave the same as the jQuery. I don't know prototype, so I can't say how to do it, but I'll +1 this if you add something that looks like it does it haha.

Comment: @Diodeus Hi, when implemented/testing this i found a slight bug. If I check a field and then refresh the page or submit and go back, the browser remember the box is checked, but it removes the class=selected from the row, so now, when i click the row and change the background color, it UNCHECKS the box. (works opposite).

Comment: @Diodeus So i guess also we need to make it so the script checks if the box is checked, and if so it adds the class selected to the row..

Comment: @Diodeus Hi, sorry to keep bugging you with this but i added a few lines to the top to check on load if things are checked and its not working. Im sure its a quick fix if you dont mind checking...http://jsfiddle.net/3XZvV/30/

Comment: Start a new question for this.